# running springMVC project on tomcat but I have to restart the web server every month. what should I do?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Hi brilliant stackoverflow users.
I've got a problem with my apache tomcat web server I didn't have before with other projects
I'm running a website using SpringMVC and JPA and also I'm using MySql database. First days I had 503 error every week and I found out that my database connection is always up and after each transaction it will not close the database connection so the web server crashed after too many requests.
Now I managed that problem using spring transaction manager. 
Now I have no error, nothing at all. My log file is clear as pure water but my web server crashes every month, so I have to restart my tomcat.
any thoughts?

I've also tried spring session manager but it didn't work.
my apache tomcat is 8.0v
I'm using java 8
and my spring version is 3.7.0

Comment: Which log file is clear? Look at Tomcat's logs, catalina.out and localhost log.

Comment: I've only got these. nothing else

Comment: 01:33:20,080 ERROR [jsp:684] User ID null
01:33:20,080 ERROR [jsp:685] Current URL /portal/web/guest/home?_20_folderId=0&_20_groupId=10157&_20_name=506&_20_struts_action=%2Fdocument_library%2Fget_file&p_auth=OZi16cv3&p_p_auth=EOIF7Uzu&p_p_col_count=5&p_p_col_id=column-3&p_p_col_pos=3&p_p_id=20&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_mode=view&p_p_state=exclusive
01:33:20,081 ERROR [jsp:686] Referer null
01:33:20,081 ERROR [jsp:687] Remote address 46.229.168.140
01:33:20,082 ERROR [jsp:689] java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: there is also this one
 com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException: Invalid authentication token

Comment: @Kayaman what do you think?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm ready to give you anything is needed. just tell me. I can share you my full catalina log. I've searched for this problem for 2 weeks and I didn't find the solution. Sorry if I'm bothering

Comment: Well, if you say that tomcat's logs have nothing of use, check out the operating system logs, check out `dmesg -T` (if on Linux) after the crash, you might be hitting a limit (such as memory or threads) that's causing it.